# Proof of Hardy inequality in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

I've often seen people use the inequality 
$$\int_{\mathbb R^3} \frac{|u(x)|^2}{|x|^2}\,dx  \leq 4\int_{\mathbb R^3}|\nabla u(x)|^2\,dx,\qquad u\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb R^3) $$
without proof, refering to it as "Hardy's inequality".

I struggled to find a direct proof of this in the literature and couldn't prove it myself. Does anyone know a straightforward proof of this or a book in which Hardy's inequality in this form is proved?

I would also be interested in the general form of this inequality, i.e. what happens if one replaces $\mathbb R^3$ with $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Have you seen Evans? Its page 296 in the second edition

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I only looked in the Index of Evans' book and there was no entry for "Hardy Inequality". This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in Evans' PDE book, page 296 in the second edition. The following discussions on this proof may also be useful,

1. [Hardy's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880855/hardys-inequality?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. [A technical step in proving Hardy's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860742/a-technical-step-in-proving-hardys-inequality)

However, it doesn't seem like the constant 4 is explicitly computed in Evans, and moreover it may be improved if the domain of $u$ is not convex. In the dimension 1 variant, it is optimal, and you can refer to [Computing the best constant in classical Hardy's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126889/computing-the-best-constant-in-classical-hardys-inequality). In higher dimensions, you may want to look at this paper [On the best constant for Hardy's inequality in $\mathbb R^n$](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/93bc/03c4343ba6f8c9f7ec54a10a007b75b915ed.pdf) by Marcus, Mizel and Pinchover, and its references.

Answer (score 7):

I learned the following integration by parts method to prove Hardy inequalities from Luca Fanelli.

Assume that all functions are real-valued and define operators on $C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb R^d\setminus\{0\})$ by
$$
Su(x)=\frac{xu(x)}{|x|^2},\qquad Au(x)=\nabla u(x).$$
Notice that the sought inequality reads
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^d} \lvert Su(x)\rvert^2\,dx \le C\int_{\mathbb R^d} \lvert Au(x)\rvert^2\, dx.$$
So, for a $k\in \mathbb R$ yet to be determined, consider
$$\begin{split}
0&\le \int_{\mathbb R^d} \lvert Su+kAu\rvert^2\, dx\\&=\int_{\mathbb R^d} \lvert Su(x)\rvert^2\, dx +k^2\int_{\mathbb R^d} \lvert Au(x)\rvert^2\, dx+2k\int_{\mathbb R^d} Su(x)\cdot Au(x)\, dx.
\end{split}$$
The last summand is
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^d} Su\cdot Au\, dx=\int_{\mathbb R^d}  \frac{x}{\lvert x\rvert^2}\cdot u\nabla u\, dx =\int_{\mathbb R^d} \frac{x}{\lvert x \rvert^2}\cdot \nabla \left(\frac{u^2}{2}\right)\, dx, $$
and since
$$\nabla \cdot \frac{x}{\lvert x\rvert^2}=\frac{d-2}{\lvert x \rvert^2}, $$
integration by parts reveals that
$$\tag{*}
\int_{\mathbb R^d} Su(x)\cdot Au(x)\, dx = -\frac{d-2}{2}\int_{\mathbb R^d} \lvert Su(x)\rvert^2\,dx.$$
Going back to the first inequality, we have that
$$
0\le k^2\int_{\mathbb R^d} \lvert Au(x)\rvert^2\, dx+(1-(d-2)k)\int_{\mathbb R^d} \lvert Su(x)\rvert^2\, dx, $$
which is a second-degree polynomial in $k$, and it attains its minimal value for $k=\frac{d-2}{2}\frac{\int \lvert Su\rvert^2}{\int \lvert Au\rvert^2}$. Plugging this into the last inequality finally yields
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^d} \lvert Su(x)\rvert^2\, dx \le \left( \frac{2}{d-2}\right)^2\int_{\mathbb R^d} \lvert Au(x)\rvert^2\, dx, $$
which is the result we wanted. $\Box$

---

**Remark 1**. The multiplicative constant $\left( \frac{2}{d-2}\right)^2$ turns out to be sharp, but proving this needs further work.

**Remark 2**. This method of proof is interesting because it has some robustness. Changing the definition of $S$ and $A$ may yield more inequalities, provided that some suitable replacement of the identity  (*) holds. For example, taking
$$
Su(x)=\frac{u(x)}{\lvert x \rvert}, \qquad Au(x)=\frac{x}{\lvert x\rvert}\cdot \nabla u(x)$$
yields the following refinement of the Hardy inequality;
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^d} \frac{u^2(x)}{\lvert x \rvert^2}, dx \le \left( \frac{2}{d-2}\right)^2\int_{\mathbb R^d} \lvert \partial_r u(x)\rvert^2\, dx, $$
where $\partial_r$ stands for the radial derivative. This inequality is tighter than the previous one, because the right-hand side is smaller; indeed, here there are no angular derivatives.

Comment: +1, how to prove the sharpness of the constant?

Comment: @partha: I wouldn't know how to do that off the top of my head. I can give a couple of link that are perhaps useful: we discussed a lot a very similar sharp constant [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/126889/8157) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3025526/8157). The inequality considered in those questions is also called "Hardy's inequality", but it involves integrals rather than derivatives. I would guess that the proof for this derivative case is very similar.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I found somehow at $f(x)=\lvert x\rvert^{-\frac{n-2}{2}}$ we have the exact equality since $\nabla f(x)=(\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_1}, \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_2},\cdots, \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_n})=\big(-\frac{n-2}{2}\big)\lvert x\rvert^{-\frac{n}{2}-1}x.$

Comment: That cannot be exactly correct, because both sides of the inequality are infinite when you plug in $f(x)=\lvert x \rvert^{-\frac{n-2}{2}}$. You need a limiting argument similar to the one of the linked questions and answers of my previous comment.

Comment: I have noticed that, but unable construct a sequence yet.

Comment: +1 for this trick. I have also seen this trick applied to proving Carleman-type inequalities.