# Uniqueness of the maximizer of the Hardy inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, optimization, harmonic-analysis

> **CONVENTION**. All functions in this post are nonnegative and defined on $[0, \infty)$.

The *Hardy operator* is
$$
Hf(x)=\frac1x\int_0^x f(y)\, dy, $$
and, as it is well known, it satisfies the inequality
$$\tag{H}
\|Hf\|_{p}\le \frac{p}{p-1}\|f\|_{p},\quad \text{for }p>1, $$
where the constant $p/(p-1)$ is the best possible, in the sense that (H) fails if it is replaced by any strictly smaller one.

In a vague sense, the function $f(x)=x^{-1/p}$ is a maximizer for (H), if one "neglects a logarithmic divergence in both sides" (as said [in this answer of Terry Tao](https://mathoverflow.net/a/48297/13042)). More precisely, as shown, for example, in [the answers to this old question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/126889/8157), some sequences that approximate $f$ also saturate (H); it is the case of
$$
f_n(x)=x^{-\frac1p -\frac1n}\mathbf 1_{(1, \infty)} $$
and of
$$
f_n(x)=x^{-\frac1p}\mathbf 1_{(1, n)}.$$

My question is, roughly speaking: is $f(x)=x^{-1/p}$ the "only" maximizer to (H)? More precisely:

> **Question**. Suppose that $$ \frac{\|Hf_n\|_p}{\|f_n\|_p}\to \frac{p}{p-1}.$$ Does there exist a sequence $\lambda_n>0$ such that $$f_n(\lambda_nx)\to x^{-\frac1 p}\mathbf 1_{(1, \infty)},$$
> almost everywhere on $(0, \infty)$?

*Remark*. The presence of $\lambda_n$ is necessary to prevent trivial counterexamples; indeed, the ratio $\|Hf\|_p / \|f\|_p$ is invariant under the scaling transformation $$f\mapsto f_\lambda(x)=f(\lambda x).$$

**FINAL NOTE**. David C. Ullrich gave an exhaustive negative answer to the present question. His answer was edited heavily and so it may be a bit hard to read. Please see my [Summary to David C. Ullrich's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3061930/8157).

Comment: What is a definition of $\|f\|_p?$

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: It is $\|f\|_p:=(\int_0^\infty f^p)^{1/p}$.

Comment: Thank you. I hope to finish my answer in time,

Comment: Ready, but.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** No, it turns out that the maximizing sequence is far from unique. See **Final Edit** at the bottom...

This is not an actual answer to your question, just a suggestion regarding how to look at it, that it seems to me may be useful.

Observe that $$Hf(x)=\int_0^1 f(tx)\,dt.$$

So if we define $$f_t(x)=f(tx)$$ we can regard $$Hf=\int_0^1 f_t\,dt$$ as a vector-valued integral. This makes (H) more or less obvious: $$||Hf||_p\le\int_0^1||f_t||_p\,dt=||f||_p\int_0^1t^{-1/p}\,dt=\frac p{p-1}||f||_p.$$This makes it clear why there is no $f\ne0$ with $||Hf||_p=\frac p{p-1}||f||_p$; that would require that the norm of the integral equal the integral of the norm, implying that for almost every $t$ we have $f_t=c_tf$, certainly impossible for $f\in L^p$, $f\ne0$.

So regarding  your question, perhaps you can get somewhere by investigating (maybe by Hahn-Banach) what follows if the norm of the integral is *almost* the integral of the norm...

**Edit** in answer to the question of what makes $x^{-1/p}$ special: **Note** first that there's no actual rigorous math from this point on, just fuzzy heuristics.

We've seen that if $f$ were a maximizer for $H$ then $f_t=c_tf$ for every $t>0$, which is impossible for a (non-zero) $L^p$ function. The obvious way to get $f_t=c_tf$ is to set $f(x)=x^\alpha$ (I think it's clear that this is essentially the only way, at least if we assume  $f$ is continuous).

So say $f(x)=x^\alpha$. Then $\int_0^1 f^p<\infty$ if and only if $\alpha p>-1$, while $\int_1^\infty f^p<\infty$ if and only if $\alpha p<-1$. So, if you promise not to tell anyone I put it this way, setting $\alpha=-1/p$ makes $\int_0^\infty f^p$ "as close as possible to finite at both endpoints".

(Hmm. An actual true fact is that $\alpha=-1/p$ is the only choice that makes $\int_{1/A}^Af^p=O(\log A)$.)

**Better yet, start over and look at it this way:** In fact $H$ is just a convolution operator on the multipicative group $(0,\infty)$. This is really the right way to look at it, for example it makes both Hardy's inequality and the fact that almost-maximizers are what they are completely transparent.

We wimp out and make a change of variables so we can consider convolutions and  Fourier transforms on $\Bbb R$ instead of on that group:

Define a surjective isometry $T:L^p((0,\infty))\to L^p(\Bbb R)$ by $$Tf(x)=e^{x/p}f(e^x).$$Define $\tilde H:L^p(\Bbb R)\to L^p(\Bbb R)$ by $$\tilde H=THT^{-1}.$$

You can calculate that $$\tilde Hf=f*K,$$where $$K(x)=e^{-((p-1)/p)x}\chi_{(0,\infty)}(x).$$Hence $$||\tilde Hf||_p\le||K||_1||f||_p=\frac  p{p-1}||f||_p.$$(Since $T$ is a surjective isometry this is exactly Hardy's inequality, made totally obvious/motivated.)

And at least formally $$\widehat{\tilde Hf}=\hat K\hat f.$$Since $K\ge0$ it's clear that $$||\hat K||_\infty=||K||_1=\hat K(0).$$
This makes it at least very plausible that the almost-maximizers for $\tilde H$ should be $f$ such that $\hat f$ is supported near the origin (for $p=2$ that's not only plausible it's even true, by Plancherel). But if $f=1$ then $\hat f$ is literally supported on $\{0\}$. And $$T^{-1}1=x^{-1/p}.$$

**Final Edit:** **No**, that's wrong.

I was unable to prove that the last paragraph above actually works, even for $p=2$, which was supposed to be clear. In fact the plausibility argument was too fuzzy. Say $p=2$.. It's true that if $f_n$ is a maximizing sequence then $\widehat {f_n}$ must in some sense have most of its mass concentrated near the origin, but it does not follow that $f_n$ must be close to $1$ on a large set. If $\widehat {f_n}$ were $L^1$ with integral $1$ that would be true, but $\widehat {f_n}$ is not integrable. What's true is that $|\widehat {f_n}|^2\to\delta_0$ weakly, but *that* says nothing about $f_n$ tending to $1$.

And in fact there are jillions of other maximizers. Temporarily define $$\phi_n(x)=n^{-1/p}\phi(x/n),$$and note that $$||\phi_n||_p=||\phi||_p.$$

It turns out that if $f\in L^p(\Bbb R)$ and $f_n$ is defined as above then $(f_n)$ is a maximizing sequence for $\tilde H$. If it happens that $f$ is continuous at the origin then $f_n$ is approximately constant on compact sets, consistent with our wrong conjecture about a maxmizing sequence being essentially unique. But if $f$ oscillates suitably near the origin then every $f_n$ does a lot of oscillation on $[-1,1]$. So "$f=1$, except truncated to lie in $L^p$" is far from the only sort of thing that maximizes $\tilde H$, hence similarly for $x^{-1/p}$ and $H$.

Proof: If $p=2$ then it's easy to see from Plancherel that $$||f_n*K||_2\to||K||_1||f||_2=||\tilde H||\,||f||_2.$$This was the first thing I noticed indicating that the conjecture was wrong, further evidence that looking at $H$ in terms of convolutions is the right way to look at it. It's not hard to give a direct proof valid for $p>1$:

First, a change of variable shows that $$f_n*K=(f*K^n)_n,$$where $(.)_n$ is defined as above and $$K^n(x)=nK(nx);$$hence $$||f_n*K||_p=||f*K^n||_p.$$But $(K_n)$ is an approximate identity, except for  the mis-normallization $\int K_n=p/(p-1)$. So $$\left|\left|f*K_n-\frac p{p-1}f\right|\right|_p\to0,$$hence $$||\tilde Hf_n||_p=||f*K^n||_p\to\frac p{p-1}||f||_p.$$

Comment: Very nice. This is a connection with the dilation group. Thank you for this beautiful answer! It is probably the case that this train of reasoning yields the uniqueness of maximizers.

Comment: Yes it is a connection with that. In fact $G=(0,\infty)$ is a locally compact abelian group, and in fact $Hf=K*f$ if you look at it right. Hence one could for  example use Plancherel to prove something about almost-maximizers in $L^2(G)$. It's not clear to me whether that's really relevant to your question, since $L^2(G)\ne L^2((0,\infty)$ (the measure implicit in $L^2(G)$ being $dt/t$ instead of $dt$.)

Comment: @DavidCUllrich: I have been thinking a little... As you show here, formally, maximizers to the Hardy inequality should be powers; $f(x)=Cx^a$, for some $a>-1$. Indeed, these are the unique solutions to the functional equation $f_t=c(t)f$. Of course this is not correct, since powers are not $L^p$ functions, as you clearly remark. Now, among all powers, the only one that "almost" maximizes is $x^{-1/p}$; if we redo [this limiting process](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3020458/8157) with another power, we get another constant. **What makes $x^{-1/p}$ so special?**

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Edit...

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Don't  miss the second edit, "**Better yet...**".

Comment: Wow!! I am also working on this problem, in my spare time. (I can't seem to put it out of my head). I am learning a lot from your contributions.

Comment: I mentioned your answer [in this computation that I did to support it](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3056438/8157).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro It turns out that "essentially $x^{-1/p}$" is _not_ the only maximizer. In fact if  $f\in L^p(\Bbb R)$ and $f_n(x)=n^{-1/p}f(x/n)$ then $(f_n)$ is a maximizing sequence for $\tilde H$ (hence $T^{-1}f_n$ is a maximizing sequence for $H$.)

Comment: [I added a summary to ease reading this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3061930/8157).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro You really didn't have to do that. I'll just donate it to charity...

Answer (score 1):

**SUMMARY OF DAVID C. ULLRICH's ANSWER**.

1. The transformation $Tf(x)=e^\frac{x}{p} f(e^x)$ is an isomorphism of $L^p(\mathbb R)$ onto $L^p(0, \infty)$ and it conjugates the Hardy operator to a convolution; $$THT^{-1} g = K_p\ast g,\qquad \text{where }\,K_p(x):=e^{-\frac{p-1}{p} x} \mathbf 1_{\{x>0\}}.$$
   In particular, the Hardy inequality $\|Hf\|_{L^p(0, \infty)}\le C \|f\|_{L^p(0,\infty)}$ is equivalent to $\|K_p\ast g\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)}\le C\|g\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)}$, and a sequence $f_n$ saturates the Hardy inequality if and only if the corresponding sequence $g_n=T f_n$ saturates the latter inequality; 
   $$
   \frac{\|Hf_n\|_{L^p(0, \infty)}}{\|f_n\|_{L^p(0,\infty)}}\to \frac{p}{p-1} \quad \iff\quad \frac{\|K_p\ast g_n\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)}}{\|g_n\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)}}\to \frac{p}{p-1}.$$

   With respect to the transformation $T$, the function $x^{-1/p}$ corresponds to the constant $1$; 
   $$
   T(x^{-1/p})=1.$$
   Thus, my question is rephrased as the conjecture that $1$ is the "essential unique maximizer" for the convolution operator $g\mapsto K_p\ast g$.
2. Since $K_p\in L^1(\mathbb R)$, by the Young inequality $$\|K_p\ast g\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)}\le \frac{p}{p-1}\|g\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)}, $$ where we used that $p/(p-1)=\|K_p\|_{L^1(\mathbb R)}$. This gives an alternative proof of the Hardy inequality.
3. By a scaling argument, for any $g\in L^p(\mathbb R)$ the sequence $g_n(x):=g(x/n)$ is such that $$\frac{\|K_p\ast g_n\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)}}{\|g_n\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)}} \to \frac{p}{p-1}.$$  (Actually, David C.Ullrich considered the differently normalized sequence $g_n(x):=n^{-1/p}g(x/n)$).
4. **Conclusion**. If $g$ is continuous at $0$, then the sequence $g_n$ constructed in the point 3 converges pointwise to a constant, and therefore the corresponding sequence $f_n\in L^p(0, \infty)$ converges pointwise to $x^{-1/p}$. But these are not the only maximizing sequences. In conclusion, the conjecture of point 1 is disproved and the answer to my original question is **negative**.

Comment: Great. I considered cleaning things up myself, decided to leave my answer as is  because the heuristics that turned out to be leading me astray could be nonetheless instructive. **Detail** The $g_n$ above presumably tend pointwise to zero, certainly so if $g$ is continuous at $0$. That's not the constant you meant - what tends to $g(0)$ if $g$ is continuous at $0$ is the differently normalized $n^{1/p}g_n$ (which of course also give a norming sequence.)

Answer (score 0):

Given

> $$\mathcal H(f(x))=\dfrac1x\int\limits_0^xf(y)\,\mathrm dy,\quad
>  \left\|f(x)\right\|_p 
> = \left(\int\limits_0^\infty f^p(x)\,\mathrm
>  dx\right)^{\frac1p},\quad p>1.\tag1$$

Let us denote
$$\mathcal H_M(f(x)) = \dfrac1M\int\limits_0^M f(x)\,\mathrm dx,\tag2$$
then
$$\mathcal H(f(x)) = \lim\limits_{M\to x}\mathcal H_M(f(x)),\quad \left\|f(x)\right\|_p 
= \lim\limits_{M\to \infty} \left(M\cdot \mathcal H_M(f^p(x))\right)^{\frac1p}.\tag3$$

Let us consider the ratio
$$R_p(f(x)) = \dfrac{\|\mathcal H(f(x))\|_p}{\left\|f(x)\right\|_p}
 = \dfrac{\lim\limits_{z\to \infty} \left(z\cdot \mathcal H_z(\mathcal H^p(f(x)))\right)^{\frac1p}}
{\lim\limits_{z\to \infty} \left(z\cdot \mathcal H_z(f^p(x))\right)^{\frac1p}}
=r_p^{1/p}(f(x)),\tag{4}$$
where
$$r_p(f(x))=\lim\limits_{z\to \infty}\dfrac{\mathcal H_z(H^p(f(x)))}{\mathcal H_z(f^p(x))}.\tag{5}$$

On the class of power functions,
$$\begin{align}
&\mathcal H(x^q) = \dfrac1x\int\limits_{0}^{x}y^q\,\mathrm dy= \dfrac1{q+1}x^q,\quad q\ge -1, \\[4pt]
&\mathcal H_z(\mathcal H^p(x^q)) = \dfrac1{(q+1)^p}\dfrac1z\int\limits_{0}^{x}x^{pq}\,\mathrm dx= \dfrac1{(q+1)^p}\mathcal H_z(x^{pq}), \\[4pt]
&\mathcal H_z(x^{pq})=\dfrac1z\int\limits_{0}^{z}x^{pq}\,\mathrm dx= \dfrac1{pq+1}z^{pq},\quad pq\ge -1,\\[4pt]
&r_p(x^q)=\dfrac1{(q+1)^p}\\
&R_p(x^q)=\dfrac1{q+1}.
\end{align}$$
If $pq+1 < 0,$ then $\mathcal H_z(x^{pq}) < 0.$

So the optimization task contains additional constraint and can be presented in the form of
$$\textrm{maximize}\quad R=\dfrac1{q+1},\quad\text{where}\quad (p>1)\wedge(pq \ge -1),\tag{6}$$
with the solution
$$R_p=\dfrac p{p-1}\quad\text{at}\quad q=-\dfrac1p,\quad p>1.\tag{7}$$

This means that $f_{opt}(x)=x^{-\frac1p}$ provides required maximum of $R_p.$

Thus, all attempts to find another function $f_{opt}$ must be unsuccessful.

Due to the Weierstrass theorem, any monotonic functional sequence in the form of
$$\{f_n(x)\},\quad f_n(x)=x^{q_n},\quad \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} q_n = -\dfrac1p,\quad q_1 \ge -\dfrac1p,$$
satisfies the OP task requirements.

If $\{f_n(x)\}$ is not monotonic, it must contain limited quantity of members with $q<-\dfrac1p.$

In partial, the sequence of
$$f_n=x^{-\frac1p-\frac1n}$$
does not satisfy the requuirements.

Comment: It seems to me that this proves that $x^{-1/p}$ is the unique maximizer **among power functions**. Which is surely true, of course; I studied this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3056438/8157). But there are other maximizers that are not power functions; see the answer by David C.Ullrich (and my answer, which is a summary to it).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I had more reach results, but deleted drafts. The interest in task is lost. There were some inequalities.

Comment: I am sorry you lost interest, but I had to assign the bounty or it would have gone to waste. Thank you for your interest in any case.